# Increment counter on each ajax success call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have written a ajax call which  is calling a rest api, on each call it is fetching data from the  database, if database found the then it should increment the counter by 1 in order to calculate the total no of records found.

```
function myFunction() {
    var count = 0
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:6060/rest/getData",
        type: "get",
        success: function(result) {
            count++;
            $.each(result, function(key, value) {
                $("#patienthide").css("display", "block");
                $("#patient").append(value.name + "<green>waiting<green>" + "<br>");
                deleteFunction(value.id);
            });
        }
        console.log(count);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(myFunction, 10000);
    $("#patienthide").css("display", "none");
});
```

but it always print 1 on console. but output should be increment the count  by one on each success call

Comment: Your `count` variable is defined locally in function. So `count` will always be 0 for each function execution. Move `var count=0` above function declaration

Comment: As above and move the `console.log(count)` inside the `success:` (where it is now in the code provided would give a syntax error, so guessing it's already inside success)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `count` variable is defined locally in function. So count will always be 0 for each function execution. Move `var count=0` above function declaration

```
var count = 0;

function myFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:6060/rest/getData",
        type: "get",
        success: function(result) {
            count++;
            $.each(result, function(key, value) {
                $("#patienthide").css("display", "block");
                $("#patient").append(value.name + "<green>waiting<green>" + "<br>");
                deleteFunction(value.id);
            });
            console.log(count);
        }
        
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(myFunction, 10000);
    $("#patienthide").css("display", "none");
});
```